# Troubleshooting Power Supply Fault

Tags: fuses

I was using my 12 V Power Supply, and suddenly a spark occured near the AC input terminals. The power supply stopped functioning. I opened up the casing and found some blackish colour near the 250V 3A fuse as shown:

[image]

I have never worked with these fuses. I wanna know if these fuses can make a big spark (as happened in my case), if overloaded. Simply put, could that spark be potentially caused by this fuse?

Comment: That the fuse blew was likely caused by the failure of another component. That is what the fuse is supposed to do and it might also produce soot when the fuse blows. The causing failure could be due to a lot of reasons: a broken filter capacitor, diode bridge, switching transistor or even a broken transformer. If the fuse was (accidentally) underrated it might have blown without another component as an initial cause. To find the initial cause you've to check these primary side components. Replacing just the fuse will not necessarily solve the cause if there really was one.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a 3 A fuse, but a 6.3 A fuse. Something broke and so much current passed the fuse that it blew with a huge spark. Perfectly normal.

Comment: Well, normal from the fuse's point of view, at least.

Comment: Pity the poor fuse. When it does its job, we say it has failed.